# Faster USB HID output

Tags: embedded, usb, hid

I'm attempting to speed up a rather sluggish bootloader. Currently I'm sending data on a single USB HID output endpoint, and as it's a low-speed device I'm apparently limited to one 8-byte packet per 10 ms interval for a whopping 800 bytes/second.

Is it possible to increase the reporting frequency somehow? Or to use multiple output endpoints in a single interface or as part of a composite device? Or perhaps to abuse the control endpoint to send additional data?

Better compression is always an alternative I suppose, but it's an area of diminishing returns, and redesigning the hardware to allow full-speed USB isn't really an option.

For the record I'd be happy with a Windows-only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or perhaps to abuse the control endpoint to send additional data?

You can use "Vendor specific requests" for that. The TI TUSB3410 Chip works that way AFAIK. Many USB stacks have the hooks for them already in place.

This requires a driver or libusb on the host side, however.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The PIC18 MCU I'm using should support them quite easily. I'm not up to writing a driver but making use of a ready-made one certainly isn't out of the question, especially with generic HID reports kept as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to speed up the upload by orders of magnitude by using SET_REPORT requests on the control endpoint, instead of declaring a separate interrupt out endpoint. That way you get all of the bandwidth available for control transfers.

Also using a larger report split into multiple segments helped reduce the number of SETUP packets needed.

Answer (score 1):

Who says you are limited to an 8-byte packet per 10ms? I don't know the exact numbers off the top of my head, but I know you can send larger packets than that. I did an HID device and was using 64-byte packets. I think I could go larger, but that limit is probably hardware-specific. What hardware are you using?

Also, have you consulted [USB in a NutShell](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml)?

Comment: Page four of "USB in a NutShell" states that: "The maximum data payload size for low-speed devices is 8 bytes"; and according to page 51 of the USB 2.0 standard: "Low-speed endpoints are limited to specifying only 10 ms to 255 ms". I may well be misinterpreting what they mean though.

Comment: Given that "low-speed" USB operates at 1.5Mbit/s, you really must be misinterpreting the text.

Comment: Those are interrupt transfers. The device can specify a polling interval at which it can interrupt the host. And that range seems to be 10ms to 255ms

Answer (score 0):

The actual limit is 8 bytes every 10ms for low-speed devices, and 64 bytes every 1ms for high-speed devices, per interrupt-based endpoint.

So it seems that the first thing to try is switching to high-speed mode, if the hardware supports it. The next thing on the list is using multiple endpoints. If you really want to get the highest possible transfer rate, the HID class is a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about Windows, but most hosts will service an interrupt endpoint faster than what the spec requires - even down to 2ms/interrupt. Try  changing your configuration descriptor to ask for a 2ms rate.

I *believe* this is actually *allowed* by the spec - the rate is a *request* that the host can comply with or not (I’ve read, for example, that some hosts will poll at 8ms even if 10ms is requested). You just can’t *rely* on any random host you plug into complying with your rate.

Edit: Hmm, no, the spec clearly says “        An endpoint for an interrupt pipe specifies its desired bus access period. […] Low-speed endpoints are limited to specifying only 10 ms to 255 ms.” Nevertheless, this has worked for me in practice…